# ページをスクロールするとチェックを外す

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML&CSS,JavaScriptについて質問です。

HTML&CSS,JavaScriptでスマホ用のメニューを作成してページをスクロールした時にinputのチェックを外したいです。
JavaScriptでスクロールしたのを検知してチェックを外そうとしたのですができません。

どこが悪いのか教えてください。

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check" />
```

JavaScript

```
if (1 < $(this).scrollTop()) {
  if (!$('#check').prop('checked')) {
    $('#check').prop('checked', false);
  }
}
```

以上がコードです。必要であればCSSも記述します。

Answer (score 0):

いただいたJavascriptはスクロール量を取得してスクロールを１より大きくしていれば、
チェックを外すという処理になっていますが、
重要な「スクロールしたことを検知する」というのができていません。

検知するためには[onscroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onscroll)を利用してみてください。

```
// 例えばwindowのスクロールを検知したいときは
window.onscroll = function(e){
  //ここにスクロールイベントが発火したときの処理を記述する
};
```

Comment: 申し訳ありません 教えていただいたとおりに書いたのですが、実行できませんでした。 別のエディタで書くとスクロール時にチェックを外すことができました。
つまりjsに問題はなくHTMLに問題があるのだと思います。 HTMLコードの問題点は自分で見つけます。